# How to use draggable headers of smart-table plugin without ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have a table in which I am using smart-table plugin for draggable column headers:- http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

```
<table st-table="collection" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th lr-drag-src="headers" lr-drop-target="headers" ng-repeat="col in columns">{{col}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in collection">
                <td>{{row.val1}}-{{row.val2}}</td>
                <td>{{row.val3 != null ? row.val3 : "&nbsp;"}}</td>
                <td><div class="width">{{row.val4 != null ? row.val4 : "&nbsp;"}}</div>
                </td>
                <td>{{row.val5 != null ? row.val5 : "&nbsp;"}}</td>
                <td>{{row.val6 != null ? (row.val3 == "1"? row.val6 : (row.val6 | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy')) : "&nbsp;"}}</td>
                <td>{{row.val7}} {{row.val8 != null ? row.val8 : "&nbsp;"}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

I know for `<td></td>` tag too I need to do ng-repeat. 
But each `<td></td>` tag consists of different conditions. It is impossible to use ng-repeat here. Can I make it draggable without using ng-repeat. Is there any way to solve my issue?

Comment: You forget to post link to your plunker.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/vB7D2sNq1FhYxzRyD8j0?p=preview. As you can see in the code only headers are draggable. Because I am not using ng-repeat for <td> tag.